# Trouble with treating dates as numbers in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to express years as numeric (not characters) so spacing represents reality better in a plot. I used `# df$years <- as.numeric(as.character(df$years))` but I get an error `Error in is.vector(breaks) : object 'years' not found`. My whole code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(years=c(1991, 1993, 1997, 2001, 2005, 2007, 2011, 2015),
                 freq=c(43.20, 52.13, 47.93, 46.29, 40.57, 53.88, 48.92, 50.92))

df$years <- as.numeric(as.character(df$years))

point <- format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)

p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=years, y=freq, label=point(round(freq,1)))) +
        geom_line(size=.7, color="#999999") + 
        geom_point(size=3, color="black") +
        geom_text(vjust=c(2, -1, -1.5*sign(diff(diff(df$freq))) + 0.5)) +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=1.25)) +
        scale_x_continuous("", breaks=years, minor_breaks=NULL) +
        scale_y_continuous("", limits=c(0, 60),
                           breaks=seq(0, 60, 10), minor_breaks=NULL))
p
```

Comment: you need: `scale_x_continuous("", breaks=df$years, minor_breaks=NULL)`

Comment: Use:  scale_x_continuous("", breaks=df$years, minor_breaks=NULL).  The reference to the dataframe is not carried into this statement.

Comment: Well, that was quite silly of me to forget `df$`. Thanks for this.

Comment: Why do you convert years to a character before converting to numeric ?

Comment: @steveb Do you mean `data.frame(years=c(1991...` and `df$years <- as.numeric(as.character(df$years))` ? If so, I am really new to `r` and this is a way of making graphs I am accustomed to. Please feel free to correct this.

Comment: @menteith The `years` column in the data frame should already be numeric.  Unless I am missing something, you should be able to remove the line `df$years <- as.numeric(as.character(df$years))`.